# php floor a number as times of 18

Tags: php, floor

How to make a function so that make floor all the number as times of 18?

example:

```
3 => 0

17 => 0

19 => 18

43 => 36

69 => 54
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$a = 19;
$a -= $a % 18; // => 18
```

Answer (score 2):

By using Modulus operator (%)

```
 $a % $b = gives the remainder of $a divided by $b.
```

In your case,

```
 $a = 3;
 $a = $a - ($a % 18);
```